# How does Replace() for SQL match?

Tags: mysql

MySQL matched `Must backout Treasury` in a replace statement to 52 distinct values. I don't understand how this is possible. So, how is MySQL matching the objects?

I did one replacement from **UK** to **United Kingdom**, and printed the distinct countries. It worked but I noticed a mistake `Must backout Treasury` as a Country. I went to replace that with `NULL`, only to have MySQL replace all Country values with `NULL`.

```
| 19 | 15:22:27 | UPDATE Trade SET country = REPLACE(country, "UK", "United Kingdom")
| 360 row(s) affected Rows matched: 23027  Changed: 360  Warnings: 0
```

I set things back

```
| 20 | 15:22:39 | SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1
```

See what has changed; Notice 52 values

```
| 21 | 15:22:51 | SELECT DISTINCT(Country) FROM Trade
| 52 row(s) returned
```

And try to replace that 1 bad value

```
| 22 | 15:23:48 | SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0  
| 23 | 15:23:48 | UPDATE Trade SET country = REPLACE(country, "Must backout Treasury", NULL)
| 9773 row(s) affected Rows matched: 23027  Changed: 9773  Warnings: 0 |
```

EDIT:
Ok, after playing around I can confirm that anytime you try to `REPLACE(Field, item, NULL)` it will completely disregard the searching and matching, and will rather drop `NULL` across every value in the Field.

So, the question remains, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have no WHERE clause. Remember REPLACE is just a string manipulation function not a search criteria

Comment: Did you get the "ONE BAD VALUE` from looking at the result of a `SELECT DISTINCT(Country)` If so please remember what DISTINCT means

Comment: That would make sense, but then why did the first replace function as I expected without the where clause?

Comment: REPLACE will only act upon data that matches  360 affected out of 23027 possible rows

Comment: My suggestion is you actually had 9773 rows with `"Must backout Treasury"` in the `country` column

Comment: To write a check before updating always run a `SELECT x FROM y WHERE col_in_question = 'The bad data'` to check how many row should be updated and to check your criteria is correct

Comment: Why are we wrapping expressions in spurious parens?   `DISTINCT` is a keyword, in the `SELECT` list it applies to all expressions in the `SELECT` list.  It's not a function.  `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM` is sufficient. Yes, it's valid to wrap expressions in parens, we can do `SELECT DISTINCT (Country) FROM ...`, the parens will be tossed away, just like the parens get tossed if we write `SELECT DISTINCT (( ( ( ((Country)) ) ) ))`.  (And concur with RiggsFolly, we can use a WHERE clause to limit the rows, and we can test expressions like `REPLACE(foo,'x',NULL)` in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: While I didn't save the output, I can attest that 9773 rows had values that weren't NULL. There's a chance that more than 1 had the bad value, but not all of them. Given the prior statement "United Kingdom" has to make up a subset, and those were also converted to NULL. Thanks for the syntax help spencer, not my main concern.

Comment: Your query will amend any row that has `"Must backout Treasury"` in the `country` column. it will search ALL rows in the table 23027 but update only those rows where it finds  `"Must backout Treasury"` 9773

Comment: Ok, clearly nobody on here actually knows how MySQL is doing to the actual matching withing the REPLACE function. I know how it should work, I'm asking why it would have failed miserably, which I'm assuming is due to an internal quirk.

Comment: I think it did exactly what you asked it to do

Comment: I suggest you do the replace and then run the distinct again and you will see the 51 other countries

Comment: There's only 1 distinct value now: NULL

Comment: If you **must** use replace then at least try replacing the value with a string since it is a string function. Perhaps your unexpected behavior is caused by passing `NULL`. Try passing empty quotes as the third parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in MySQL, most string operations that involve `NULL` values wind up evaluating to `NULL`. This behavior makes sense in terms of thinking of `NULL` representing the idea "I don't know what the value of this is".

Consider:

```
 SELECT CONCAT('abc',NULL)
```

returns `NULL`. If I append an "unknown" value to 'abc', the result is going to be "unknown". Similarly,

```
 SELECT REPLACE('abc','d',NULL)
```

putting an "unknown" value into a string is to result in an "unknown" value. So this expression returns `NULL`. It doesn't matter if `'d'` appears in `'abc'` or not.

---

Normally we test expressions in a `SELECT` statement before we incorporate them into an `UPDATE` statement. This lets us confirm the rows that are being matched, and the results of expressions, e.g.

```
 SELECT t.country 
      , REPLACE(t.country, 'Must backout Treasury', NULL) AS country_repl_null
      , REPLACE(t.country, 'Must backout Treasury', '')   AS country_repl_empty
   FROM trade t
  ORDER 
     BY ...
```

Comment: Ok ok, but shouldn’t the backend just be written so if “d” is not in there then break? Like why would it try to put NULL in when it can’t find a location of “d” to begin with?

Comment: It's a shortcut in the evaluation, likely done at optimization time rather than run time. MySQL evaluates the expression `REPLACE(x,y,NULL)` and that gets shortcut evaluated NULL. It's as if we had written just `NULL`. Same thing happens with `CONCAT(x,NULL)`.  The only time that shortcut wouldn't happen is when we used an expression that wasn't known to be NULL for all rows...  `CONCAT(t.x,t,y)`  ,,, we don't know the values of x and y until we look at each row.

Comment: Ahhhh alrighty then! Thank you both. I was debating my sanity.

Comment: Working with `NULL` values can make anyone question their sanity!

Answer (score 1):

Because `REPLACE()` matches your input string with the values. It checks if the input string is a substring of the field value and if so, it replaces it with your value. So when you tried to replace `UK` with `United Kingdom` it searched for all occurrences of `UK` in your data and replaced them all.

Instead of a replace, just use `WHERE` to specify the trouble records and do the replace.

`UPDATE Trade SET country=NULL WHERE country="Must backout Treasury"`
**OR**
`UPDATE Trade SET country=NULL WHERE country LIKE "%Must backout Treasury%"`

Comment: It only searched the Country field no? But yes, it correctly found and replaced UK with United Kingdom. The confusion I'm having it that it seems to have found "Must backout Treasury" in every single Country field, which wasn't possible given "United Kingdom" was now at least 1 of the 52 distinct values.

Comment: DISTINCT Will show you ONE ROW in the output even if there are 1,000,001 rows containing a single value !!!!

Comment: Yes it only searched the `Country` field. As @RiggsFolly mentioned, `DISTINCT` only shows a single value which gave you the false idea that there was only a single **Must backout Treasury** record when there was multiple. So it went and replaced every single occurrence of that in the `Country` field

Comment: I'm aware of DISTINCT, perhaps you're over looking the the fact there there is 51 other distinct values and yet MySQL matched "Must backout Treasury" to all of them. Which would be possible if ever entry had that as a substring, but we all know that "United Kingdom" was 1 and I know that 50 others didn't have that as a substring....it's not much of a country

Comment: So when you run `UPDATE Trade SET country = REPLACE(country, "Must backout Treasury", NULL)` and then run the `DISTINCT` call, does it say 1? `| 9773 row(s) affected Rows matched: 23027  Changed: 9773  Warnings: 0 |` This just says it changed a lot of rows. Does your table have **9773** records?

Comment: It had 9773 values that weren't NULL, it has 23027 rows total but 23027-9773=13254 rows where it the country was already NULL